# Asyncio wait_for one function to end, or for another

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

My code has 2 functions:

```
async def blabla():
    sleep(5)
```

And

```
async def blublu():
    sleep(2)
```

asyncio.wait_for as I know can wait for one function like this:
`asyncio.wait_for(blublu(), timeout=6)` or `asyncio.wait_for(blublu(), timeout=6)`
What I wan't to do, is to make asyncio wait for both of them, and if one of them ends faster, proceed without waiting for the second one.
Is it possible to make so?
Edit: timeout is needed

Comment: i cannot get the standard `.waitfor()` for work from the python docs.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74510354/exception-has-occurred-timeouterror-exception-no-description,  which version are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) with the `return_when` kwarg:

```py
# directly passing coroutine objects in `asyncio.wait` 
# is deprecated since py 3.8+, wrapping into a task
blabla_task = asyncio.create_task(blabla())
blublu_task = asyncio.create_task(blublu())

done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
    {blabla_task, blublu_task},
    return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
)

# do something with the `done` set
```

Comment: Is it possible to use timeout with this?

Comment: Yes, use the `timeout` kwarg