# Exception has occurred: TimeoutError exception: no description

Tags: python, websocket, timeout, python-asyncio, timeouterror

I am specifically using python version `3.10` to run a websocket (or any long `asyncio` process) for a **specified period of time** which is covered in the python docs. The `.wait_for()` method looks like the correct solution.

I run this code (from the docs):

```py
import asyncio

async def eternity():
    # Sleep for one hour
    await asyncio.sleep(3600)
    print('yay!')

async def main():
    # Wait for at most 1 second
    print('wait for at most 1 second...')
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(eternity(), timeout=1.0)
    except TimeoutError: 
        print('timeout!')


asyncio.run(main())
```

The docs are here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=wait_for#asyncio.wait_for

However, I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: TimeoutError
exception: no description
```

...basically, the `TimeoutError` exception is not handled as expected.

My research shows that others have struggled with errors, for example here:
[Handling a timeout error in Python sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865685/handling-a-timeout-error-in-python-sockets)

but the fixes are either aged (not relevant for 3.10) or do not work. I also notice that the docs specify this "*Changed in version 3.10: Removed the loop parameter*". So i am only interested in version `3.10` and above.

So I am wondering how to get the min reproducible example working or what i have done wrong please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the **TimeoutError** so it can jump down to the **print('timeout')** or can use this example to output the error

```
except Exception as exc:
    print(f'The exception: {exc!r}')
```

Comment: I was going to post similar as a solution, but this catches other errors, whereas ideally like to catch the `TimeoutError`....  what did the `!r` do ?  i have not seen this before ?!?

Comment: I have upvoted this because it works.  although i have used this `print('some exception...', type(e))`...

Comment: I don't know what "!r" is for, but it seems to be forcing the string, I also found it in the website you sent me.

Comment: In an f-string, `{exc!r}` is replaced by `repr(exc)`.  `{exc}` is replaced by `str(exc)`.  See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: @Paul Cornelius this knowledge is new to me, thank you for answering the question

Comment: @PaulCornelius. was unaware of this. So basically, `Exception as e: ...  print(str(e))` would have been sufficient.

Comment: print(repr(exc)) is the equivalent of print(f"{exc!r}").  print(exc), print(str(exc)), print(f"{exc}") and print(f"{exc!s}") are essentially the same thing.  I'm not sure what's the difference in actual output between repr(exc) and str(exc) when exc is an Exception.  With exceptions I almost always print the full traceback (traceback.print_exc()) or use Python's logging features.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of TimeoutErrors in Python.

Replace except TimeoutError with except asyncio.TimeoutError and you’ll be good.

UPDATE with full example:

```
import asyncio

async def eternity():
    # Sleep for one hour
    await asyncio.sleep(3600)
    print('yay!')

async def main():
    # Wait for at most 1 second
    print('wait for at most 1 second...')
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(eternity(), timeout=1.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError: 
        print('timeout!')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Apparently the example in asyncio’s docs is wrong (or at least misleading).  If you look at CPython’s source code, asyncio.TimeoutError is a different exception from TimeoutError up to Python 3.10, and was changed to an alias to TimeoutError in 3.11.

Comment: noted and appreciated. I actually went for this `except Exception as e: ... if str(type(e)) == "<class 'asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError'>":` as it catches all errors and filters for the `asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError` error.  If you have a code example that would be most helpful.